# How to add editing and validation rules to CL programming? (As400)

Tags: ibm-midrange

***please note this is a 'expand your knowledge' (optional task) for college, not an assignment***

I have a physical file called `INVFILE` and a logical file called `INVFILE1`

I have the CL program called `INVCL99`

this these are my columns for `INVFILE1`

```
R INVFILE 1
  PARTDESC
  ONHAND
  UNITCOST
  STOCK
  PARTNUM
K PARTNUM
```

this is the code for my CL program

```
PGM

         SNDUSRMSG MSG('EXECUTING INVENTORY PROGRAM, PRESS ENTER')

         CHGDTA DFUPGM(INVENTORLB/INVENTORY) FILE(INVENTORLB/INVFILE1)

ENDPGM
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is to validate the `STOCK` column. as it stands it only accepts 1 character, or no characters.

I'd like to validate it so that it can only accept 1 **specific** character `*` or be left blank, nothing else can be inputted.

I've been googling trying to find some sources that will help me out with this, but unfortunately I can't find anything. Any chance someone can tell me where to look? or tell me what I need to do?

Also, not sure if I should create another question for this, but I have been trying to use numerous ways to be able to input decimals in my DFU programs example : Total Amount Purchased 2300.29, I've tried floats which caused problems, and I've tried packed decimals, but I can't seem to figure out how to allow decimals / periods to be inputted.

Thanks.

Comment: I applaud you for trying this in CL. Honestly, why would you? RPG is designed for this and can do it much easier than CL ever can. CL is more so for running a bunch of programs together. I am sure it is possible, but I would write and RPG program to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: i didn't even know, our professor hasn't even started talking about RPG lol but it is good to know that it would be a lot easier using RPG so in the future i won't give myself a headache. What I will do is try both, I will start with RPG for it being easier, then I will learn to do it in CL, as a just in case kinda thing lol. Thanks Mike!

Comment: You showed the **names** of fields, records and files, but no data definitions. Without knowing data types and sizes, we can't know the way decimal points and decimal fractions shouls be entered. (We don't even know if a field is numeric or character.) BTW, DDS probably isn't the best choice for your database files, though you'll probably need to learn it. SQL could be better for anything new.

Comment: If a DFU will do the input, there pretty much won't be any `editing and validation` in the CL itself. It'll all be done by database rules. It's fairly easily possible in CL, but you're already doing a DFU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DFU enables specifying for a column, from the **Work with Fields** panel, 2=Specify Extended Definition, then **2**=*Change* for the *Validity checks* prompt, where at the **Specify Validity Checks** panel the arguments of the DDS `VALUES` keyword can be specified on the *List of values* prompt if\when the *Relational Operator* prompt is set to **LS**=*List of values*.

Because the specifying of `VALUES()` in a database file DDS [PF or LF] has no effect outside of what is provided by program generators and the DDS compiler for Create Display File (CRTDSPF) [the database cares not about the designation for actual I\O], the only benefit in having the `VALUES` coded in the PF or LF DDS is to ensure that both DFU and CRTDSPF *see* the same input restrictions; the PF often the better choice to carry the attribute up to the LF and into those other places.  Note: the DDS compiler for Create Printer File (CRTPRTF) recognizes other keywords, but not VALUES, because the PRTF is output-only vs allowing input like the DSPF].

I forget how to code the DDS for the DSPF to override the inability to type the period for the decimal point, but I seem to recall with the addition of an Edit Code (EDTCDE) and removal of the CHECK keyword that keying the decimal point is possible; ask the DFU to save the DDS and then review what that feature generated, and then a customized version can be created and used. The other irritating effect for DFU is the forced Upper-Case; as I recall that is a DSPATR keyword setting that can be changed. The interactive DFU code generator may, like the ability to code limited values, specify capabilities for either\both of those issues, but I do not recall and a cursory look I did not see anything.

Comment: I see that my approach to what I was doing, was wrong, I was thinking well in C programming during coding is where validity checks were done so maybe its the same with CL, didn't think about the DFU lol, leading to me asking the wrong question. Once again CRPence you've gone above and beyond what I was expecting. Any chance you're going to be a professor at Seneca College soon? lol. This was perfect and I can pass on the information to the rest of the class that's in the same boat, thank you again CRPence, very much appreciated.

Comment: In the CLP in the OP, despite being a _compiled_ program, the CL is functioning solely in the capacity as a **Control Language** rather than as a typical HLL, and effectively just deferring all DataBase and screen I/O to the CHGDTA interactive utility; the CHGDTA merely invokes the DFU program generated via STRDFU, to perform the DataBase I/O, and presents the Display File generated via that same STRDFU as the means for the WS Display Device I/O. A CLP has limited capability to perform DB I/O via RCVF and the ability to do WS I/O via SNDRCVF, so could do the work directly, but would be daft.

Answer (score 3):

They right place to do this is in the DDS for the physical file...

You can use the [VALUES keyword](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakb/rzakbmsttdvalue.htm) to restrict the valid values of the field.

To place the equivalent of an basic SQL CHECK constraint on the field.  In fact, you could simply define an SQL check constraint if you'd like.

As far as your decimal input question, packed or zoned decimal is the correct choice.  I don't know why you'd have problems inputting the decimal point.  But I've never used DFU programs.  You should probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't seem to get it going. I placed it in the logical file (that's ref to the physical file), and I tried making it hex format `VALUES(X'2A')`, and value only format `VALUES('*')` but I can't seem to make it so when the DFU loads it, it stops from inputting anything but a *. I have tried putting in the physical file and got an abnormal end when compiling. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Code `VALUES(' ' '*')`. Note that the IBM i is an EBCDIC system, not ASCII. While 0x2A is an asterisk in 7-bit ASCII encoding, the EBCDIC 8-bit code point is 0x5C. Best avoid coding anything in hex code points except when\until the impacts are understood; normally [assuming the User Profile is properly setup for language\locale attributes], the keyboard character for the visible glyph is all that need be coded to identify the proper character. If while exiting STRDFU to create or change the program, the option to "Save DDS for Display File" is chosen, the identical VALUES will appear there.